# How to change properties of angular material elements/components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, angular-material

Hi i am a beginner in angular and I recently used a material spinner in one of my angular components

```html
<mat-progress-spinner [id]="demo1" value="30" mode="indeterminate" diameter ='32' ></mat-progress-spinner>
```

Now in my typescript file i wanted to access this spinner element and change its mode to determinate and its display to block so i did it like this

```js
let b= document.getElementById("demo1") as any;
    b.mode="determinate";
    b.style.display="block";
```

The style property was changed however the mode wasn't changed. So i am wondering why its happening . Is it because mode is not a predefined property ? Is there a way to change the mode without binding mode to a variable or property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mat-progress-spinner is an angular component. getElementById only gives you access to the HTML element.

You need to get a reference to the spinner component in it's parent component in order to manipulate it.

In your parent component's TS file, put this:

```
@ViewChild(MatProgressSpinner) mySpinner;
```

or use a named reference such as #mySpinner on your spinner (if you've got several of them):

```
<mat-progress-spinner #mySpinner [id]="demo1" value="30" mode="indeterminate" diameter ='32' ></mat-progress-spinner>
```

In this case you get a reference to it like this (in the parent component's TS file):

```
@ViewChild('mySpinner') mySpinner: MatProgressSpinner;
```

Comment: Glad to hear, that :) Can you please click on the checkmark (just under the 0 score) then to mark my answer satisfactory?

Comment: can i ask you one more question ?

Comment: Sure, go ahead :)

Comment: i am using <mat-progress-spinner> inside a ngFor loop, so there are multiple spinner components in my parent component , is there a way to access each <mat-progress-spinner> properties like mode , value individually using a function in my parent component ?

Comment: You can use @ViewChildren(MatProgressSpinner) which will give you a QueryList of all spinner components in your template.

Comment: i used  @ViewChildren(MatProgressSpinner) spinner : QueryList<MatProgressSpinner> to get all the spinners and then inside a function assigned this query list to a variable using , spinners= this.spinner.toArray() and then used  spinners[0].value=60;
      spinners[0].mode ='determinate' the mode is getting changed to determinate and you can see it in browser , its value property is changed when i see in console, but its not reflected in my page/view . please help